# Outlook add-in to launch when using File Explorer Send to - Mail Recipient

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have a Outlook add-in that adds visual things to the email compose window and then catches the send-event, does stuff, and then let Outlook send or cancel it.

Works fine, but if I use the send file option from explorer, without outlook running, it will not start the add-in. The window is missing all the added UI elements. When I click send button it will start the add-in. I get a welcome screen we coded and it starts logging the add-in startup debug messages.

But it will not catch the send event or do anything else for that matter. The last log message shows init was completed. The Outlook process will be left in the task manager. If I open Outlook after that I will see that the email I sent is in outbox. Without any modifications the event handler would have done.

Is there anyway to get add-into run in this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this problem was because I had only run the project in debug mode from Visual studio. I had never installed it from the package.

Once I had ran the installer it begun to start the add-in as soon as I chose "send to mail recipient" thus fixing the problem.